Python Matplotlib - How to plot a grouped bar chart
Suppose I already have the following labels list and data dict:
labels = ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5"]

data = {
    "Data 1": [12, 20, 17, 16, 32],
    "Data 2": [12, 20, 17, 16, 32],
    "Data 3": [12, 20, 17, 16, 32]
}

How do I plot a grouped bar chart with 5 blocks each containing 3 bars?

There is a nice tutorial in Matplotlib official site:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html
You can just simply replace species with your labels and penguin_means with your data.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.25  # the width of the bars
multiplier = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')

for attribute, measurement in data.items():
    offset = width * multiplier
    rects = ax.bar(x + offset, measurement, width, label=attribute)
    ax.bar_label(rects, padding=3)
    multiplier += 1

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_xticks(x + width, labels)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', ncols=3)
plt.show()


You can try something like this:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns



data = {
    "labels" : ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5"],
    "Data 1": [12, 20, 17, 16, 32],
    "Data 2": [12, 20, 17, 16, 32],
    "Data 3": [12, 20, 17, 16, 32]
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data = pd.melt(data, id_vars =['labels'], value_vars=['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3'])

ax1 = sns.barplot(data = data, x='labels', y='value', hue='variable')

ax1.set_xlabel('Labels')
ax1.set_ylabel('Values')

for container in ax1.containers:
    ax1.bar_label(container)

ax1.legend(loc='upper left');

Output:

